# How can I do more elegantly several _.has checks?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object like this

```
myObject:{"property1": "valueX",
          "property2": "valueY",
          "property3": "valueZ",
          "property4": "valueV",
          "property5": "valueW"}
```

and I want to make sure that none of my object properties names match several strings.

The most intuitive way I found is this one:

```
if( !_.has(myObject, "TestingValue1")&&
    !_.has(myObject, "TestingValue2")&&
    !_.has(myObject, "TestingValue3")&&
    !_.has(myObject, "TestingValue4")){
//do something
}
```

But if I have too much property names to check, it is becoming quite a large piece of code.

I am trying to come up with a more elegant solution. I feel it is almost ok but I does not appear to work (it always returns true). Here it is:

```
var TestingValues = ["TestingValue1", "TestingValue2", "TestingValue3"]

if (!_.every(TestingValues, _.partial(_.has, myObject))){
//do something
}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong? How should I declare `TestingValues`?

**EDIT**:

@Sergiu Paraschiv I used different values in `myObject` and the test array only for making it easier to read. Of course I tested it with identical values.

You are right, I just realized it works. I didn't at first because it does not work as intended. I mixed things up: I want to return *false* if **any** of the item in the string array matches **any** of the attributes of `myObject`

Comment: Like you defined it `myObject` does not have any of the properties you are checking for. That coupled with the `!` in front of that `_.every` call and what's inside `TestingValues` guarantees it'll always be `false`. It seems to be working for me if I put properties that make sense in that object: http://jsfiddle.net/v0m4j0km/

Comment: I edited the question and just realized I need to use `_.some` instead of `_.every`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do :

```
var TestingValues = [ "TestingValue1", "TestingValue2", "TestingValue3" ];

if(!_.isEmpty(_(myObject).pick(TestingValues)){...
```

or as you suggested yourself :

```
if (!_.some(TestingValues, _.partial(_.has, myObject)))
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. Can you edit your post to move your "picked" values into a var array and add my solution too? My solution would be `if (!_.some(TestingValues, _.partial(_.has, myObject))){` I'll validate afterwards, this will make a nice answer

Comment: You could even move the call to `partial` outside of the call to `some` so that the partial function is only created once.

Comment: Aaaah, micro-optimization, the root of evil, and yet it feels so good :-)  I did a quick try but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
_some(TestValues, function(test) { return _.indexOf(_.values(myObject), test) != -1});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 var testingValues = ["TestingValue1", "TestingValue2", "TestingValue3"];

 var myObj = {
    "property1": "valueX",
    "property2": "valueY",
    "property3": "valueZ",
    "property4": "valueV",
    "property5": "valuez"
};

var result = _.every(myObj, function(value, key, obj){
    return !_.contains(testingValues, value);
});
console.log(result);
```